# Dynamic variables for changing backgroundPosition

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I've found a few loosely related answers but none that have the level of variability that I need.

I am trying to create a color-changing chip palette similar to what you would find on an automobile website: when a paint swatch is clicked, the main image's background position will change, giving the illusion that the paint color has changed. I'm still new to javascript, but *think* this is the most elegant way to go about it. Can someone help get the syntax into an actual working script?

defining css:

```
#target { 
     background: url("/images/center-stage.jpg") no-repeat; 
     background-position: 0 0;
}
```

function on the external script file:

```
function colorChange(x,y)
{
    var x=("x" + px); // i don't get how to format this stuff
    var y=("y" + px);
    document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition="(,)"; // this doesn't really go here, does it?
}
```

and the html call(s):

```
<a href="#" onclick="colorChange(0,50)"><img src="/images/swatches/red.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="colorChange(0,100)"><img src="/images/swatches/yellow.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="colorChange(0,150)"><img src="/images/swatches/blue.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="colorChange(0,200)"><img src="/images/swatches/green.jpg"></a>
```

and so on.

to make matters more complicated there are 2 color variables; just as a car website would have exterior interior color choices, this script also needs to have exterior and interior color options (black or white exterior with 4 possible interior colors).

I thought the best way to do it is to have all exterior options on the y axis and all interior options on the x axis, but need to define the calls in such a way that clicking red, yellow, blue or green will move the x-axis but keep current selection the same (and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the JS to this:

```
function colorChange(x,y) {
    document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition=x+'px '+y+' px'; 
}
```

The background image will begin to move.  The reason why it wasn't working in your example:

```
function colorChange(x,y)
    {
        var x=("x" + px); // i don't get how to format this stuff
        var y=("y" + px);
        document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition="(,)"; // this doesn't really go here, does it?
    }
```

Is this statement:
    var x=("x" + px);

This won't work because "x" is a variable and should not be quoted.  Also 'px' is a string, and SHOULD be quoted, so that statement becomes:
    var x = x+'px';

Now, in the statement:
    document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition="(,)";

You can set the value directly without having to use 'var x = x+"px"', so it becomes:

```
document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition=x+'px '+y+' px';
```

Also, just out of curiosity, are you using jQuery or a jQuery type JS library?
Because instead of saying:

```
document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition=x+' '+y
```

You can say:

```
$("#target").css('background-position', x+'px '+y+'px');
```

---

** EDIT **

To update only the value you need and not both x and y:
Well with CSS, there is no background-position-x or equivalent. So you'd have to keep a variable in JS that holds each of the X and Y values.  Then your change function could update the variable...and then do the background-position change.

Look at this code:

```
// variable outside of function() scope
var xposition, 
     yposition;

// Update values of xposition and or yposition
function updatePositions(axes) { // Should be {x:0,y:0}
    // Check to see which axis was passed in x, y or both, then update values
     if (typeof(axes.x) !== 'undefined') xposition = axes.x;
     if (typeof(axes.y) !== 'undefined') yposition = axes.y;

//Call function to actually move BG image
colorChange();
}

// Function move BG image, using variables declared above
function colorChange() {
    // Use xposition and yposition which are changed by JS function above
    $("#target").css('background-position', xposition+'px '+yposition+'px');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    updatePositions({x:0,y:0}); // Initialize to starting position
});
```

---

The {x:0,y:0} code above is just a way I'm using to pass on parameter into a function with multiple values.
{} signifies a Javascript 'Object'...so you can say this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.x = 150;
obj.y = 200;
console.log(obj);
```

Outputs: Object {x: 150, y:200}

---

HTML
(Note you can pass in x and y or just x or just y)

```
<a href="#" onclick="updatePositions({x:0,y:50})"><img src="/images/swatches/red.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="updatePositions({x:0,y:100})"><img src="/images/swatches/yellow.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="updatePositions({x:0})"><img src="/images/swatches/blue.jpg"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="updatePositions({y:200})"><img src="/images/swatches/green.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: After thinking a bit on this, you might consider using class names to describe your background positions, just for ease of maintainability.  So for each color combination, just make a CSS rule with the background-position.  Then you can apply the CSS rule to the <div> instead of math with your JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for this! i thought about that first, but with 24 (and growing) different options the CSS would start getting out of control.

Comment: oh man, the jquery library option was way easier. thanks eli! so for the exterior choices, is there a javascript equivalent of "*"? is it possible to call a change to X and not to Y in the html?

Comment: fantastic, eli, you're a lifesaver! thank you for also taking the time to explain /why/ instead of just posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
function colorChange(x,y)
        {
            var positionX = x + "px";
            var positionY = y + "px";
            document.getElementById("target").style.backgroundPosition = positionX + " " + positionY;
        }
```